# no matching function for call to c++ string error

Tags: c++, string

I am trying this code to perform the following function : given an input file and a word(string) output should be the lines in the file containing the given word along with the line number. But I am getting an error saying "no matching function for call to ..." in the line where I am performing string operation (strstr). Here is my code. Please help me solve this. I am facing the same error in other programs also where ever I perform operations involving strings.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int x;
char c;
ifstream iFile1, iFile2;
ofstream oFile;
char file1[50], file[50];
char word[50];
cout << "First file?\n";
gets(file1);
std::string str;

cout << "Word?\n";
gets(word);
iFile1.open(file1);

while (std::getline(iFile1, str)) {
    x++;
    if (strstr(str, word)) {
        cout << "%d\t,x";
        cout << str;
    }
}
}
```

error: `no matching function for call to 'strstr(std::string&,char[50])'
      if(strstr(str,word))
                       ^`

Answer (score 4):

`char * strstr (char * str1, const char * str2 );`

This is the signature of the `strstr` function, which requires both elements to be `char*`, but you are passing as first element a `std::string&`.

To fix this, try:

```
 if (strstr(str.c_str(), word))
```

The `c_str() method` returns a `char *` to an array that contains the elements of the string

Also please note that the `gets` function is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

Not the right answer, but still important to point out:

`<string.h>` is not `<string>`

`<string.h>`, and `<cstring>`, are header files defining several functions to manipulate *C Strings* and arrays ([Source](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/))

`<string>` defines `std::string`, which has the handy member function `.c_str()` allowing you to use functions which want a parameter of `char*`